# Convert specific json values as dictionary values in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

this is my example JSON file.

```
[
 {
  "Sl No.": 1,
  "Questions": "Who is known as ‘Father of computers’?",
  "Option A": "A.Vannevar Bush",
  "Option B": "B.Charles Babbage",
  "Option C": "C.Howard Aiken",
  "Option D": "D.John Atansoff",
  "Answers": "Charles Babbage",
  "Level" : 2
 },
 {
  "Sl No.": 2,
  "Questions": "Which among the following has low speed storage?",
  "Option A": "A.CD-ROM",
  "Option B": "B.Extended storage",
  "Option C": "C.Magnetic disks",
  "Option D": "D.Magnetic tapes",
  "Answers": "Magnetic tapes",
   "Level" : 1
 }
]
```

I'm trying to convert it into a python dictionary which should have question and answer pairs like this:

```
dic ={"Who is known as ‘Father of computers’?": "Charles Babbage","Which among the following has low speed storage?": "Magnetic tapes" }
```

And as of now I'm using this method to convert into dictionary:

```
json_file = open("import.json")
data = json.load(json_file)

questions = []
answers = []


for i in range(len(data)):
    questions.append(data[i]["question"])
for i in range(len(data)):
    answers.append(data[i]["answer"])

easy = dict(zip(questions, answers))
```

Here I'm iterating through the JSON file to find question and answer values and appending them to an empty list. Then I'm using the zip function to convert these 2 lists into dictionaries. I know this isn't a very optimized approach and as my application scales, I'll have to create multiple dictionaries for which I have to create 2 lists for every dictionary and then zip again. Is there any easier and better approach?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension here. There, you iterate over an iterable and put key value pairs separate with a colon. That will generate a dictionary for you. In code, that reads like

```py
result = {d["Questions"] : d["Answers"] for d in data}
```

Note that I habe used the keys as shown in the example not the ones used in your code.

Answer (score 0):

using `get` will not throw error if `Questions` or `Answers` does not exist, you can pass second parameter in `get` to return `that value` in case of any question or answer key does not exist

```
final = {each_item.get('Questions'): each_item.get('Answers') for each_item in my_list}
```

Answer (score -1):

A bit roundabout way of getting there, but in Python 3.8+ you could also use the walrus `:=` syntax combined with a straightforward `dict` comprehension:

```py
data = [
 {
  "Sl No.": 1,
  "Questions": "Who is known as ‘Father of computers’?",
  "Option A": "A.Vannevar Bush",
  "Option B": "B.Charles Babbage",
  "Option C": "C.Howard Aiken",
  "Option D": "D.John Atansoff",
  "Answers": "Charles Babbage",
  "Level" : 2
 },
 {
  "Sl No.": 2,
  "Questions": "Which among the following has low speed storage?",
  "Option A": "A.CD-ROM",
  "Option B": "B.Extended storage",
  "Option C": "C.Magnetic disks",
  "Option D": "D.Magnetic tapes",
  "Answers": "Magnetic tapes",
   "Level" : 1
 }
]

result = {(v := list(d.values()))[1]: v[v[0] + 2].split('.', 1)[-1]
          for d in data}

print(result)
```

Of course, that'll probably end up being terribly inefficient. If you want to avoid shooting yourself in the foot, you'll be better off using the simplest and most elegant solution that is available:

```
result = {d['Questions']: d['Answers'] for d in data}
```

Out:

```
{'Who is known as ‘Father of computers’?': 'Charles Babbage', 'Which among the following has low speed storage?': 'Magnetic disks'}
```